# dragonfly rails 4 image_tag error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dragonfly-gem

I'm building my photography portfolio in Rails 4.1.6 and Ruby 2.0.0p576.

I have 'collections' which have many 'photos'.

I am using dragonfly 1.0.10 for image uploads.

**Collections Model**

```
    class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :admin
      has_many :photos
    end
```

**Photos Model**

```
   class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :collection
    extend Dragonfly::Model
    dragonfly_accessor :image
   end
```

**Collection Controller**

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :html, :xml, :json

 def index
  @collections = Collection.all
 end

 def new
  @collection = Collection.new
  respond_with (@collection)
end

 def create
  @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)
  @collection.save
  respond_with (@collection)
 end

 def edit
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

  if @collection.update(collection_params)
   redirect_to @collection
  else 
   render 'edit'
  end    
 end

 def show
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
 end

 def destroy
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
  @collection.destroy
  respond_with (@collection)
 end

 private
  def collection_params
   params.require(:collection).permit(:name, :desc, photos: [:image] )
  end

end
```

**Photos Controller**

```
    class PhotosController < ApplicationController

     def new
      @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
      @photo = @collection.new
     end

     def create
      @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
      @photo = @collection.photos.create(photo_params)
      redirect_to collection_path(@collection)
     end

     private
      def photo_params
       params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
      end

   end
```

This is storing my photos for me correctly.

But on my collection show page, I'm getting a "NoMethodError in Collections#show undefined method `image'.

In terminal, I get the following error: 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `image' for #):

Code for the show page is below:

**collections/show.html.erb**

```
    <h1><%= @collection.name %></h1>

    <p><%= @collection.desc %></p>

    <% @collection.photos.each do |photo| %>
     <div>
      <%= image_tag @collection.photos.image.thumb('400x300#').url %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
```

I'm an absolute rails n00b and need some help as to how to fix this and be able to view all the photos of the collection on its show page.

Please help!

Comment: Try this `<%= image_tag photo.image.thumb('400x300#').url %>`

Comment: Thanks Pavan! This works for me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong usage of the `each` loop:

```
<% @collection.photos.each do |photo| %>
   <div>
     <%= image_tag photo.image.thumb('400x300#').url %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

[`Read How does iteration work in Ruby?`](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/a-wealth-of-ruby-loops-and-iterators/)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I will definitely read more into this.